# AD620 In-Amp, single 5v supply, reference pin affecting gain

Tags: instrumentation-amplifier

Given [the datasheet here](http://www.analog.com/static/imported-files/data_sheets/AD620.pdf), I can't explain my observations with my AD620AN test circuit.

The circuit:

- Supply: +5v / 0v (Well regulated)
- 1k potentiometer across the supply, with the wiper going to both the reference pin and the negative input
- +ve/-ve inputs: K-type thermocouple. (41uV/K)
- Gain resistor: 100 Ohm (Gain of 500).

It seems that the gain is strongly dependent on the voltage of the reference pin. If I set the pot at precisely 2.5v, I get roughly the expected gain. But even slighly higher or lower and the gain reduces significantly. (For example, just +/- 0.05V change in reference reduces gain by about 10% for output signals of +/- 100mV). I've been taking measurements with a standard multimeter.

I haven't done meticulous testing with this, but none the less have lost a fair bit of hair. Is there something obviously wrong with what I'm doing? I must have run through the figures in the datasheet two dozen times. Is it the circuit at fault? Or my measurements? Or both?

Comment: With a multimeter it's difficult to measure gain - what was your method?

Answer (score 8):

Notice the small block diagram in Fig.2 if the [AD620 datasheet](http://www.analog.com/static/imported-files/data_sheets/AD620.pdf).

[image: simplified block diagram a 3-OpAmp instrumentation amplifier from the AD620 datasheet]

Here's a larger diagram from a datasheet of a similar InAmp with a 3-OpAmp topology ([LT1920](http://www.linear.com/product/LT1920)).

[image: block diagram of a 3-OpAmp instrumentation amplifier from the LT1920 datasheet]

Notice that **VREF is not a high impedance input**.  In order not to skew the differential output stage, VREF should be connected to a low impedance output.  A voltage divider by itself is not a low impedance output.  However, the voltage divider can be buffered.

[image]

I have built and tested a similar circuit.  (In my case, the VREF came a source other than a potentiometer, though.)

Comment: I got bit by this error once. I had connected the ref pin of an instrumentation amp straight to a potentiometer. It has interesting effects.