# Voltage source for Vref or Voffset

Tags: voltage-regulator, voltage-reference, dc-offset, input-impedance

I have a DiffAmp [AD8132](http://www.analog.com/static/imported-files/data_sheets/AD8132.pdf) following an OpAmp [LT1818](http://cds.linear.com/docs/en/datasheet/18189fb.pdf). A 1.5V voltage source, such as **voltage divider, voltage reference, or voltage regulator** should be connected to the **B** input pin of the DiffAmp to compensate for the offset of the original signal. I was wondering if output impedance of a voltage source would be as crucial as for Vref pin of the In-Amp, which is discussed in [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/84427/which-is-the-correct-voltage-reference-for-a-single-supply-instrumentation-ampli) thread.

[image]

I plan to connect the output of the OpAmp directly to point **A**, and a voltage source  directly to the point **B**. If the impedance matter in this case too, then which voltage source would be the best choice? Do I need any additional compensation resistors before the **A** and **B**? The Vcm (pin 2) of the DiffAmp is set to 1.5V to provide a common mode signal at the output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, low impedance is important.

The differential input impedance (looking into either input) is 696 ohms when the diffamp is in balance, so if you're looking for 0.1% accuracy you need the source impedance to be well under an ohm.

You can use another of the same kind of op-amp (LT1818) to buffer the 1.5V reference, which could be derived from a higher voltage reference with a voltage divider.

This is not the usual application for a differential amplifier, seems like a lot of parts just to remove 1.5V from the input signal.

Edit: For a voltage divider you can use something like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2feTwXx.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Try to make R2 about 1/5 to 1/10 of the pot value, and choose R1 and R3 to get enough range to account for all variations for sure, but not too much more.

Comment: Thank you. My next stage is a differential input ADC. So, if I connect two LT1818s to A and B respectively, my input impedance should be well matched? This seems to be a better choice than using some voltage reference?

Comment: Also, if I decided to use voltage divider, would a trimmer be 'ok' in terms of noise as compared to two resistors? I sample a video signal. Want to be it clean.

Comment: A trimmer should not cause any problems. It's good engineering practice to minimize the range. I'll edit the answer a bit.